# Variable in included jsp?

Tags: jsp, variables, include

i have a JSP-File which includes another JSP file. In both of them I need a special variable.
This is a part of the code of the JSP that includes the other JSP:

```
<%String logged = request.getParameter("logged");
out.print(
 "<h3> Auftragliste </h3>" + "Eingeloggt als: "
+ logged
+ "<br /><hr /><br />");
%>

<!-- DAS IST DIE EIGENTLICHE AUFTRAGLISTE, INNERHALB DES DIVS -->
<div id="AutoUpdte">
    <jsp:include page="AuftragListe.jsp" />
</div>
```

This request of "logged" works fine. Now here is a part of the included JSP:

```
+ "<form method='POST' "
        + "name='Auftrag"
        + i
        + "' action='Annehmen'>"
        + "<input type='hidden' name='ID' value='"
        + auftraege.get(i).ID
        + "' />"
        + "<input type='hidden' name='von' value='"
        + auftraege.get(i).von
        + "' />"
        + "<input type='hidden' name='nach' value='"
        + auftraege.get(i).nach
        + "' />"
        + "<input type='hidden' name='object' value='"
        + auftraege.get(i).object
        + "' />"
        + "<input type='hidden' name='reward' value='"
        + auftraege.get(i).reward
        + "' />"
        + "<input type='hidden' name='logged' value='"
        + logged
        + "'>"
        + "<center>"
        + "<input class='auftragannehmen' type='submit' value=''/> "
        + "</center>"
        + "</form>"
```

In this JSP I request the variable "logged" as i did above. But when i click the button and the form starts the next step can't access the "logged" variable.

Where is my mistake?

Thank you!

Edit: The included JSP definitely can't access the variable. But how can it access this variable?

Answer (score 0):

The request is typically used to store attributes that must be accessible to all the servlets and JSPs handling the request. But here, it's unnecessary since the variable is the value of a request parameter. Just use `request.getParameter("logged")` as you do in the parent JSP.

That said, you seem to have completely missed the point in using JSPs, which is to avoid generating HTML markup by using Java code and ugly String concatenations (which could be done from a servlet directly). Learn the JSTL and the JSP EL, and avoid scriptlets like the plague in your JSPs. For example, your first scriptlet should be rewritten as:

```
<h3> Auftragliste </h3>
Eingeloggt als: <c:out value="${param.logged}"/>
<br /><hr /><br />
```

Note that the use of `<c:out>` here makes sure the parameter is properly HTML-escaped, and thus avoids all kinds of XSS attacks.

Comment: When i change my first scriplet to your code the whole page doesn't work anymore :S

Comment: Please elaborate. What happens exactly? And of course, like every taglib, its implementation must be in the webapp's classpath, and the taglib must be declared at the top of the JSP. See http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info, and take some time to learn how it works before using it.

Comment: The parent JSP can't acces the logged variable, which is of course clear.

But there is a nother problem. We are not allowed to use this. Our professor said we are not allowed to use everything which needs a "$" in the code :S

Comment: Unless this restriction is justified by the fact that he wants to teach you the EL later, choose another school: your teacher doesn't teach best practices, and is stuck in 2000. Else, use `request.getParameter("logged")` in the included JSP.

Comment: He will explain that later, yes.

I tried request.getParameter("logged") and it works for the parent JSP, but not for the included one. I have no idea why :(

Comment: So here is a short update: I made a System.out.println(logged) in the included JSP, just to see in the console what the value of this String is. I changed the include declaration to this:

  <jsp:include page="AuftragListe.jsp" flush="true">
      <jsp:param name="page" value="<%=logged%>" />
  </jsp:include>

Maybe another important information for this: This include Tag is in a div which is refreshed every 5 seconds.
First the variable logged has the value null. Then for a short time it has the correct value and after a short time later it is null again. Where is the problem now?

Answer (score 0):

Use a request attribute to pass the 'logged' value

```
request.setAttribute("myLogged",logged);
```

read the attribute value in the included JSP file like this:

```
String logged = request.getAttribute("myLogged");
```

or just

```
 ${myLogged}
```